# Can I use Bing map API in my iOS application offline?

Tags: ios, bing-maps, offline

I want to develop **iPhone** application in which I want to display **map** for the **location** entered in the search bar,it works fine when there is internet connection but fails to display map **offline**. I am using **Bing map API's**.

Comment: i know nothing about bing map api, but I think you need connection to download map content, which I expect to be too big to be stored locally on an iPhone.

Answer (score 6):

For using bing map API's  internet connection is must. Either you should create you own database or display an error message when internet connection is not there.

Answer (score 1):

it is possible but not allowed to store a local copy.

maybe a legal way would be to buy a licence for the bing maps server

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: ohh i see.. i'm a stackoverflow-noob soorry >.<